# Find the length of an integer in C++

Tags: c++

In Java, I use

```
int length = String.valueOf(input).length();
```

to find the length of an integer.

My question is: Are there any similar ways to do so in C++?
I have already tried the for loops and while loops such as:

```
while (input > 0){
    input/=10;
    count++;
```

So, apart from the loops are there anything else available in C++. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string

Comment: @CrakC - I already said no loops.

Comment: @n.m. - Can you please cite an example? If possibe.

Comment: @Raphael There are other solutions on the page as well, including a similar version of the one posted below. Did you go through all of that before posting a new question?

Comment: @CrakC - Sorry, I just saw the accepted answer.

Comment: @Raphael Never mind. Please do a thorough search before posting a new question. If you get a solution from there then please remove this question.

Comment: @Raphael : I see you are new on StackOverflow. If you feel that one of the answers has adequately satisfied your question, you are encouraged to accept it by clicking on the green tick next to the answer. This helps mark the question as solved with accepted solution, and allows users to focus on other questions. Thanks :)

Answer (score 10):

If you want an exact counterpart of what you have written in Java, you can use:

```
int length = to_string(input).length();
```

Note that `to_string` is a C++11 feature. Also, be careful with negative numbers.

Comment: I don't think the OP is interested in C++11, coz the question ain't tagged so!

Comment: @HappyCoder : Or the fact that C++11 tag doesn't pop up automatically many times. I think if the person doesn't want it, he/she should explicitly specify it. But even then, thanks for your views :)

Comment: Even if the answer doesn't meet the OP's requirements, I think that it may still be useful to others using C++11.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

The number of digits can be calculated without converting to a string first by using the number's logarithm:

```cpp
std::size_t intlen(int i) {
    if (i == 0) return 1;
    else if (i < 0) return 2 + static_cast<std::size_t>(std::log10(-i));
    else if (i > 0) return 1 + static_cast<std::size_t>(std::log10(i));
}
```

The logartihm is only defined for positive numbers, so negatives and zero have to be handled separately, counting the `-` sign as an additional character. Replace `log10` by `log2` to obtain the number of binary digits (this is possible for any base).

Note however that converting to strings first (e.g. by using `std::to_string`) is a locale-dependent operation and can thus yield different results for different language settings - some locales insert a thousands separator (e.g. `100,000`) which will not show up using the above formula.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

> unsigned int number_of_digits = 0;
>
> do     {
>           ++number_of_digits; 
>           n /= base;    }     while (n);
>
> // n is your base number.

Comment: **"So, apart from the loops"**

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Talking about pre-C++11, you can use the same approach, but with [`sprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/).

Convert integer to a char array, and then get its length:

```
char buffer[30];

int length = sprintf(buffer, "%d", input);
```

Here is the [working IDEOne example](http://ideone.com/SICuff).

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the loops there is recursion. For example, for positive integers you can do:

```
unsigned int len(unsigned int n)
{
    return n ? len(n/10)+1 : 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!